# Use of JDBC to upload Excel File to SQL Server 2012 table

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I want to upload an excel file to sql server 2012 table but not able to do so. I'm doing it in my Java Application but getting this message.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot initialize the
>   data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for
>   linked server "(null)".

My SQL Server 2012, Office and Database Engine all are 64 bit. When I do it using simple query like below it works. But fails when I use JDBC Statements.

```
Use AMFB
    SELECT * INTO temp_31_Jan_2017 FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;Database=C:\SQLBACKUP\upload\ACTIVE_31_JAN_2017.xlsx','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

My sql connectivity string is
`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AMFB;integratedSecurity=true`
I placed sqljdbc jar and dll files in appropriate directories. But still getting this issue.

Comment: This is way more simple that you think, you can't reach the database at all ;) `Cannot initialize the data source object`. Check the parameter you are using

Comment: @AxelH : Can you explain what kind of parameter you are talking about?

Comment: How are you connecting to your sql server from the JDBC ?

Comment: Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AMFB;integratedSecurity=true");

Comment: My guess is that you'll get the exact same exception when you do it from SQL Server Management Studio: it is likely not a Java/JDBC specific problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : But its strange that I'm not getting this exception from SQL Management Studio.